# Avoid long tuple definitions in haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, hxt

For my work with [hxt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt) I implemented the following function:

```
-- | Construction of a 8 argument arrow from a 8-ary function. Same
-- implementation as in @Control.Arrow.ArrowList.arr4@.
arr8 :: ArrowList a => (b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4 -> b5 -> b6 -> b7 -> b8 -> c)
                -> a (b1, (b2, (b3, (b4, (b5, (b6, (b7, b8))))))) c
arr8 f = arr ( \ ~(x1, ~(x2, ~(x3, ~(x4, ~(x5, ~(x6, ~(x7, x8)))))))
               -> f x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 )
```

As mentioned in the haddock comment the above function `arr8` takes an 8-ary function and returns a 8 argument arrow. I use the function like this: `(x1 &&& x2 &&& ... x8) >>> arr8 f` whereby `x1` to `x8` are arrows.

My question: Is there a way to avoid the big tuple definition? Is there a more elegant implementation of `arr8`?

Info: I used the same code schema as in the function [arr4](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.3/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v%3aarr4) (see [source code of arr4](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.3/docs/src/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#line-61))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works, though it depends on some quite deep and fragile typeclass magic. It also requires that we change the tuple structure to be a bit more regular. In particular, it should be a type-level linked list preferring `(a, (b, (c, ())))` to `(a, (b, c))`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Arrow

-- We need to be able to refer to functions presented as tuples, generically.
-- This is not possible in any straightforward method, so we introduce a type
-- family which recursively computes the desired function type. In particular,
-- we can see that
--
--     Fun (a, (b, ())) r ~ a -> b -> r

type family   Fun h      r :: *
type instance Fun ()     r =  r
type instance Fun (a, h) r =  a -> Fun h r

-- Then, given our newfound function specification syntax we're now in
-- the proper form to give a recursive typeclass definition of what we're
-- after.

class Zup tup where 
  zup :: Fun tup r -> tup -> r

instance Zup () where 
  zup r () = r

-- Note that this recursive instance is simple enough to not require 
-- UndecidableInstances, but normally techniques like this do. That isn't
-- a terrible thing, but if UI is used it's up to the author of the typeclass
-- and its instances to ensure that typechecking terminates.

instance Zup b => Zup (a, b) where 
  zup f ~(a, b) = zup (f a) b

arrTup :: (Arrow a, Zup b) => Fun b c -> a b c
arrTup = arr . zup
```

And now we can do

```
> zup (+) (1, (2, ()))
3

> :t arrTup (+)
arrTup (+)
  :: (Num a1, Arrow a, Zup b n, Fun n b c ~ (a1 -> a1 -> a1)) =>
     a b c

> arrTup (+) (1, (2, ()))
3
```

If you want to define the specific variants, they're all just `arrTup`.

```
arr8 
  :: Arrow arr 
  => (a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g -> h -> r)
  -> arr (a, (b, (c, (d, (e, (f, (g, (h, ())))))))) r
arr8 = arrTup
```

---

It's finally worth noting that if we define a lazy `uncurry`

```
uncurryL :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurryL f ~(a, b) = f a b
```

then we can write the recursive branch of `Zup` in a way that is illustrative to what's going on here

```
instance Zup b => Zup (a, b) where 
  zup f = uncurryL (zup . f)
```

Comment: I had to look up the use of `~`, so here's a link for someone else: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Lazy_pattern_matching

Comment: Yup! It's not material to the core technique here, just mimics what @tampis was asking for. Note that I also use `(~)` for a different reason in one of the comments where `(a ~ b)` means "`a` is the same type as `b`".

Comment: I had it in an earlier, more complex version until I noticed I had stopped using it :)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: Thanks for your elegant solution! ;-)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: Do you know of a package on hackage already providing your solution?

Comment: I don't know of one offhand. I learned this stuff by examining `fixed-vector`. If you're willing to play with some more complex types you might be able to replace your types with those from `fixed-vector` productively.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be writing

```
arr8 f = arr (uncurry8 f)
```

I don't know if we can write a generic `uncurryN n f` function (probably not), but I can offer you a pointfree `uncurry_n` for each `n` in a systematic manner like so:

```
uncurry3 f = uncurry ($) . cross (uncurry . f) id
uncurry4 f = uncurry ($) . cross (uncurry3 . f) id
...
uncurry8 f = uncurry ($) . cross (uncurry7 . f) id
```

where

```
cross f g  = pair (f . fst) (g . snd)
pair f g x = (f x, g x)
```

Comment: Note that `cross` is usually written [`***`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-) (and `pair` is [`&&&`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%26%26%26%29)).